# I would like to select the bottom 3 lowest numbers within a group using R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have this script

```
CHECK <-TOP3BYNumber %>%
arrange(Number) %>%
group_by(Number) %>%
top_n(3)
```

This gives me the highest 3 values grouped by the column Number using dplyr.

I would like to instead of getting the top three highest values to get the top 3 lowest values.

i tried 
    top_n(-3) and this does not work.

Comment: When not specified, `top_n` will sort by the last column in your table. What is the last column in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
TOP3BYNumber %>%
      arrange(desc(Number)) %>%
      group_by(Number) %>%
      slice(seq_len(3))
```

Or with `row_number()`

```
TOP3BYNumber %>%
      arrange(desc(Number)) %>%
      group_by(Number) %>%
      slice(head(row_number(), 3))
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked like exactly how i needed it to.